# Infinite loop while deleting first node

Tags: c, linked-list

In Linked List while trying to create a program to find and delete an element in an linked list I am unable to delete the very first node.

**My Program:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;
typedef struct node NODE;
main()
{
    NODE *t,*u,*v;
    int i,n,f=1;;
    for(i=0;i<=20;i+=2)
    {
        t=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        t->num=i;
        t->next=NULL;
        if(start==NULL)
        {
            start=t;
            u=t;
        }
        else
        {
            u->next=t;
            u=t;
        }
    }
    t=start;
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-->",t->num);
        t=t->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\nEnter Any value to delete");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    t=start;
    u=t;
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        if(t->num==n)
        {
            u->next=t->next;
            v=t;
            t=t->next;
            free(v);
            f=0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            u=t;
            t=t->next;

        }
    }
    system("cls");
    if(f)
        printf("Not found\n");
    else
        printf("Deleted\n");
    t=start;
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-->",t->num);
        t=t->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}
```

This works with all the elements except the element of very first node when i enter the value of first node to delete it goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: When you are deleting first node you are removing start address..

Comment: Off topic but you don't need to cast here : `t=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));`

Comment: Because that's not something that causes you trouble but I felt worth to notify.

Comment: Please **use whitespace** in your code.

Comment: why is it off topic ?

Comment: add if statement before u deleting and assigning 
    if(start == t)
       start->next = t->next 
see if it helps and update us .
in the end you assigning t= start so it goes to infinite loop since t->next is null so you always have nulls

Comment: Also, I'm not really inclined to debug a code where the variables are named `u`, `t`, `v` and `f`.

Comment: @Maxime oh we thought the question was off topic and wondered why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are deleting the first node it means you are deleting the start address of your linked list,You need to manually check for first node by adding this line of code:

```
if(start->num==n)
{
t=start;
start=start->next;
free(t);
}else
```

Your full code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;
typedef struct node NODE;
main()
{
    NODE *t,*u,*v;
    int i,n,f=1;;
    for(i=0;i<=20;i+=2)
    {
        t=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        t->num=i;
        t->next=NULL;
        if(start==NULL)
        {
            start=t;
            u=t;
        }
        else
        {
            u->next=t;
            u=t;
        }
    }
    t=start;
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-->",t->num);
        t=t->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\nEnter Any value to delete");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    t=start;
    u=t;
    if(start->num==n)
    {
        f=0;
        start=start->next;
        free(t);//t is start
    }
    else
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        if(t->num==n)
        {
            u->next=t->next;
            v=t;
            t=t->next;
            free(v);
            f=0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            u=t;
            t=t->next;

        }
    }
    system("cls");
    if(f)
        printf("Not found\n");
    else
        printf("Deleted\n");
    t=start;
    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-->",t->num);
        t=t->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add if statement before you deleting

```
   if(start == t) 
        start->next = t->next;
```

In the end you assigning t= start so it goes to infinite loop since t->next is null so you always have nulls.

because in the last loop you are using:

```
   t=start;
   while(t!=NULL)
   {
       printf("%d-->",t->num);
      t=t->next;
   }
```

So if you freed the first node you freed the start pointer as well and t will alwais be NULL thats where infinite loop comes from.